# Remove html attributes from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, vue.js

I'm creating an internal tool that a designer can paste exported svg code into a text area and it will display that html code in a syntax highlighter (https://antoniandre.github.io/simple-syntax-highlighter/)

When they paste their code like this

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18.135" height="12.365" viewBox="0 0 18.135 12.365">
  <path id="Path_4" data-name="Path 4" d="M10.067,5.649a8.054,8.054,0,0,1,7.27,4.534,8.1,8.1,0,0,1-14.541,0,8.054,8.054,0,0,1,7.27-4.534m0-1.649A9.749,9.749,0,0,0,1,10.182a9.741,9.741,0,0,0,18.135,0A9.749,9.749,0,0,0,10.067,4Zm0,4.122a2.061,2.061,0,1,1-2.061,2.061,2.062,2.062,0,0,1,2.061-2.061m0-1.649a3.709,3.709,0,1,0,3.709,3.709A3.715,3.715,0,0,0,10.067,6.473Z" transform="translate(-1 -4)"/>
</svg>
```

I want to remove the widths, heights, and any id's associated with the pasted string like this

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18.135 12.365">
  <path d="M10.067,5.649a8.054,8.054,0,0,1,7.27,4.534,8.1,8.1,0,0,1-14.541,0,8.054,8.054,0,0,1,7.27-4.534m0-1.649A9.749,9.749,0,0,0,1,10.182a9.741,9.741,0,0,0,18.135,0A9.749,9.749,0,0,0,10.067,4Zm0,4.122a2.061,2.061,0,1,1-2.061,2.061,2.062,2.062,0,0,1,2.061-2.061m0-1.649a3.709,3.709,0,1,0,3.709,3.709A3.715,3.715,0,0,0,10.067,6.473Z" transform="translate(-1 -4)"/>
</svg>
```

I'm using Vuejs to do this so I'd prefer JS of jQuery to solve this issue. I've tried a few things with JS but haven't been successful in removing these attributes.

Comment: Maybe you tried this but have you considered just keeping what you need instead of removing what you don't need, meaning that you just pull out the selected values from the string and create a new element with those values.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this regex:

```
\s*(width|height|id|etc)="[^"]*"
```

---

Explication:

`\s*`: replace any spaces

`(width|height|id|etc)`: replaces `width`, `height`...

`[^"]*`: replace any character that isn't a `"` repeated between 0 and Infinite times